# Facebook SDK on Unity Test Users returning empty data sets

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue whereby I had previously had three test users, and by adding new users and using the same code, I could not get the user's data. Here is my code:

```
public void myScores (Action<IGraphResult> callback = null) {
    FB.API ("/me/scores", HttpMethod.GET, delegate(IGraphResult result) {
        Debug.Log("MyScoresCallback");
        if (result.Error != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError(result.Error);
            return;
        }
        Debug.Log (result.RawResult);

        if (callback != null) {
            callback (result);
        }
    });
}
```

From the Debug.Logs, for the three initial test users, this returns the users name and score object. For the new test user and my own access token, this returns an empty data set.

Isn't it supposed to work for all test users including myself?

Thank you!

Comment: facebook only shows you your friends' scores, is the new test user your friend?

Comment: @NikaKasradze Hi Nika, all my test users are friends of each other, so they're supposed to return their values. I have a separate call function that pulls friends' scores which works perfectly fine. It's just the "/me/scores" that doesn't seem to work properly.